# res.locals variable empty or out of scope?

Tags: node.js, express

so when I log into my website and navigate within the same url (ex: localhost/**private**/xxxx), the res.locals.user returns an object.

When I go out of the range (ex: localhost/xxxx), `res.locals.user` is empty.

***/ app.js***

```
...
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(require('./controllers'));
...
```

---

***/ controllers / index.js***

```
router.use('/private', require('./member.js'));
router.use('/admin', require('./admin.js'));

/* Some basic routes. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { ... });
});
```

After loggin in `res.locals.user` is still empty here

---

***/ controllers / member.js***

```
router.use(function isMember(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    return next();
  }
  req.flash('error', 'WHY YOU LITTLE!');
  res.redirect('/login');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/private/index');
});

router.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/private/somehting');
});

router.get('/darkside', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/private/darkside');
});
```

`res.locals.user` correctly returns the user, whether I navigate to */private*, */private/something* or */private/darkside*

Is it cause I use a middleware route when using `router.use('/private', require('./member.js'));` ? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I simply had to add

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
  }
  return next();
});
```

before all my routes and remove `res.locals.user = req.user;` from the **member.js** file

So it would give me this:

***/ controllers / index.js***

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
  }
  return next();
});

router.use('/private', require('./member.js'));
router.use('/admin', require('./admin.js'));

/* Some basic routes. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { ... });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`res.locals` is an object passed to the rendering engine of your app. You can set the user details by `req.session.user = user` in passport authentication strategy.So that you can access the user from any of your route.

Comment: The problem doing so, is I would need to add the user to each of my routes (got around 30+). res.locals.user avoids this as it's right for the taking in my template files.